# holoviews won't plot stacked bar only individual bars

Tags: jupyter-notebook, stacked-bar-chart, hvplot

I have an interactive dashboard that i want to plot a stacked bar graph on however when i plot either it only plots individual bars. I also get an error when i use hvplot.bar(i.e., dt_melt.hvplot.bar) so i have to use kind ='bar' with stacked = True

Here is the code  and snippet of the output i am getting:
`dt_plots =dt_melt.hvplot(kind='bar', stacked=True,
x='Date',
y='value',
by='Group',
width=800,
height=600,
groupby='Group',
legend=False,
xlabel='',
bar_width=0.5,)

```
 dt_plots`
```

[[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faNIi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfBap.png)|

I tried to melt() before stacking and it didn't work